# MongoReactiveRepository - find by list of values (IN operator)

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux

I try to find all Offer where Offer.ProductProperties.id IN (String1, String2...)

```
public interface OfferRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Offer, String> {

    @Query("{'properties.id': {'$in': ?0}}")
    Flux<Offer> findByPropertiesIds(List<String> propertiesId);
```

Unfortunately I get null... Why? I have no idea...

But this works:

```
@Query("{'properties.id': ?0 }")
    Flux<Offer> findByPropertiesId(String propertiesId);
```

Offer Document:

```
    @Document(collection = "offers")
    public class Offer {

        @Id
        private String id;

        @NotNull
        @DBRef
        private ProductProperties properties;
}

        @Document(collection = "product_properties")
        public class ProductProperties {
            @Id
            private String id;
    (...)

}
```

I've tried also to use ReactiveMongoTemplate, but without success:

```
List<String> propIds = products.stream()
                .map(product -> product.getProperties().getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("properties.id").in(propIds));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Offer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution:

```
@Query("{'properties.$id': {'$in': ?0}}")
    Flux<Offer> findByPropertiesIds(List<ObjectId> propertiesId);
```

I had to add $ to id and chage String to ObjectId as reference ids to the related documents.